# uploading to attached/mounted EBS volume with scp?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I'm having a weird problem-- I mounted an additional ebs volume to my ec2 instance and when I'm on my ec2 instance I have no problem transferring files to and from it to various places but I can't upload from my local computer to the attached volume-- whenever I specify it via scp it says "permission denied"

my ebs extra volume is mounted on my ec2 instance at ~/sdf so from my local console I type (replaced my dns for security):

scp -i trial.pem output.avi ec2-user@ec2-**-**-**-104.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/sdf/output.avi
scp: /home/ec2-user/sdf/output.avi: Permission denied

if i try to do sudo before the above it asks me for a password-- but i have no idea what password its asking me for? its not the admin password on my local machine, i tried that...

how do i fix this?

Comment: also i already changed the chmod on /sdf to 777 so that's not the problem

Comment: Have you tried using the regular path (/home/sdf, I guess) instead of ~/sdf? Maybe your local shell is trying to interpret ~/ instead of the remote shell.

Comment: yeah- it says no such directory, which makes me think its understanding my path ok but is just denying me permission

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the 2nd volume mounted at /sdf, and then some sort of link in your home directory.

If the file is mounted at /sdf and has 777 you should be able to scp to ec2-user@instance:/sdf/

What is the output of the mount command?  ls -l /?